# py3compile fails to compile

Tags: python

I'm trying to byte compile my python3 script.
With the regular pycompile (Python2), I've found that it only accepts scripts whose names end in `.py`.

How do I get py3compile to successfully compile my Python3 scripts?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? What did you try, and why didn't it work for you?

Comment: @Murphy For example, I could write a Python3 and name it something like `script.py`. I would run `py3compile script.py` and there would be no output file. `pycompile script.py` works, even if script.py were written in Python3 instead of Python2, but obviously does not run.